# Fragment and android:text:"@string/..."

Tags: android, fragment

Basically, I'm using Fragment in my project and all works fine

But I found that I can't return the strings from the value folder to the android:text

Example :

android:text="Hello World"  << this works fine in Fragment , return Hello World in my TextView

android:text="@string/text1"   << this doesn't work in Fragment !  it return @string/text1 in my TextView as it is

Can someone tell me a solution for this problem ?

my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

main

```
public class AboutMe extends Fragment {

    @Override   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_aboutme, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: could you show your xml layout?

Comment: I have posted the xml layout

Comment: If you want access to the string programmatically: `getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.text1);` If you want via XML, you are doing it right. I don't know what is the error in this case.

Comment: You don't have to include the getActivity() to get a String, just getResources().getString(R.string.text1); works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access it by:

```
getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.text1);
```